# What is the best practice to write an API for an action that affects multiple tables?

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework, api-design

Consider the example use case as below.

You need to invite a Company as your connection. The sub actions that needs to happen in this situation is.

1. A Company need to be created by adding an entry to the **Company table**.
2. A User account needs to be created for the staff member to login by creating an entry in the **User table**.
3. A Staff object is created to ensure that the User has access to the Company by creating an entry in the **Staff table**.
4. The invited company is related to the invitee company, so a relation similar to friendship is created to connect the two companies by creating an entry in the **Connection table**.
5. An Invitation object is created to store the information as to who invited who onto the system, with other information like invitation time, invite message etc. For this, and entry is created in the **Invitation table**.
6. An email needs to be sent to the user to accept invitation and join by setting password.

As you can see, entries are to be made in 5 Tables.
Is it a good practice to do all this in a single API call?
If not, what are the other option.
How do I maintain data integrity if it is to be split into multiple APIs?

Answer (score 1):

If the actions need to be atomic, then it's definitely best to do this in a single API call. Otherwise, you run the risk of someone not completing all the tasks required and leaving the resources in a potentially conflicting state.

That said, you're not updating a single resource, so this isn't a good fit for a single RESTful resource creation call (e.g., `POST /companyInvitations`) -- as all these other things being created and stitched together might lead to quite a bit of confusion.

If the action you're doing is "inviting a Company", then one option is to use Google's "custom method" syntax (`POST /resources/1234:action`) as defined in [AIP-136](https://google.aip.dev/136). In this case, you might do `POST /companies/1234:invite` which says "I want to invite Company #1234 to be my connection".

Under the hood, this might atomically upsert (create if resources don't already exist) all the right things that you've listed out.

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider when approaching an API call where multiple things happen when called, is how long those downstream actions take. Leaving the api call blocked isn't the best idea in the world while things are processing in the background.

You could consider (depending on your usecase) taking in the api request, immediately responding with a 200 status, and dropping the request onto an internal queue for processing. When your background service picks up the request it can update whatever needs to be updated and manage the transactions appropriately etc. This also caters for horizontal scaling scenarios where lots of "worker" services can be deployed to process the requests.

As part of this you could consider adding another "status" endpoint where requests can be made to find out how things are going. To avoid lots of polling status requests you could also take in callback details as part of the original api call which then gets called when the background processing is complete. Or you could do both!